# How do I route all my desktop's traffic through the Shadowsocks client?

Tags: networking, routing, proxy, traffic

I've got a Rust implementation of Shadowsocks (no plug-ins) server, [which can be found here](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-rust), running on my VPS but I have no idea how to configure a client correctly so that all my desktop's outgoing traffic would go through my Shadowsocks proxy. I have no such issue on my Android Shadowsocks client.
I need some kind of a script which starts Shadowsocks client and routes all the traffic coming from my system through it (just like what `wg-quick` does in case of Wireguard). How should I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which OS you're using, but you can usually configure a socks proxy in your browser. There are also global means to send everything over a certain interface that is bound to the socks server. But I need to know what OS you have.

Comment: 1. I'm using a Linux system.
2. I need the whole traffic to be routed through the proxy, not just a browser one.